# In Rails, how can I retrieve the object on a belongs_to association, without going through the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, belongs-to

Consider the following setup:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
end
```

And this console session:

```
>> p = Parent.find 41
>> p.some_attr = 'some_value'
>> c = p.children.build
>> c.parent
```

By watching my log files, I can see that c.parent is querying the db for the parent object.  I want instead to access the existing in-memory object (p), because I need access to the parent's some_attr value, which is not yet stored in the database.  Is there any way of doing this?  c.parent(force_reload=false) doesn't get me there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use :inverse_of to set it. Read more about it [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many#972-Undocumented-inverse-of-option).

Comment: Yes, :inverse_of was developed precisely to fit this need.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveRecord doesn't endeavor to guarantee that in-memory objects for the same database objects are all the same. This is something that DataMapper does guarantee.

I realize your example is probably simplified in order to ask your question, but just from a naive look at it -- why don't you just use p instead of c.parent?

Another possibly helpful suggestion, save the update to parent to the db:

```
p = Parent.find 41

# do this...
p.some_attr = 'some_value'
p.save

# OR this...
p.update_attribute(:some_attr, 'some_value')

c = p.children.build
c.parent
```

I'm not sure if `c.parent(false)` ("don't reload from the db") will do the trick here, since it's a fresh Child object. But you can try that too.

Comment: You are right about the example being simplified - in real life I am working with a validation scenario in which the child's validity depends on attributes of the parent (actually, attributes of a sibling object collection).  So in the child object's validation code I need to get to the parent as it exists in memory, with all of the attributes that just got assigned/updated when the html form was submitted, and not the stale version that is sitting out in the db.  I am using accepts_nested_attributes_for :children, so I know everything is set up as I need it in memory.

Comment: You can do the whole thing in a transaction -- that way you can save the parent, then check the validation, if validation fails, you roll back.